# Why do I not have any laravel error pages on my server?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.0. So when I was messing around with laravel on Vagrant it was really easy to debug because of the laravel error pages. Now that I've installed again on an actual apache server, I get no error pages.

I have forced a error by typing a variable that wasn't there and all I get is a WSOD with chrome telling me its a 500 error. I take that variable away and everything works fine, so I know whats causing my 500 error.

Edit: I have already changed 'debug' to true in my config/app file.

Any idea on how to get these error pages back?

Comment: Do other pages work? i.e. can you browse and use your site ok?

Comment: see handling-errors on the doc http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#handling-errors

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I could try multiple routes, but I was trying to force an error so that I could see if the error page was working, and its not.

Answer (score 0):

When installing laravel on a server you must ensure that you set the correct permissions to the **storage** directory

```
sudo chmod o+w storage
```

Comment: Still just a WSOD. I've also tried php artisan optimize which didn't do anything for me either.

Comment: What is the PHP version on your server ? ` php --version`